# Options to create a web installer which downloads actual installer from remote server

Tags: windows, deployment, installation, installshield

I have a installer implementation task, 
the requirement is :

1. small size : less than 1m
2. it will connect to a server and
   download some description file to
   tell the user what software they can
   choose to install and also get the
   real software download address
3. after the user make their choice, the installer will download the corresponding software and automatically install
4. this installer may be reused by future product

These software user can select is pre-compiled installer as well. more precisely, eclipse based.

The functionality of the installer could be very similar to MSN Live installer which lists all msn live software including live messenger, video creator and so on to let user choose, once the choice is made, the installer will download the software and install. the installer itself is less than 1.5m

I need some suggestion what technology or technique I can utilize to minimize task load?

I have the following resource:
redhat server, iis server probably can be granted.
installshield license
visual studio 2008/2010 license
I'm afraid these are all i got. A new software license purchase isn't very likely to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a custom bootstrapper:

- Using your InstallShield license or Visual Studio setup project you create installation packages for your applications. These packages can then be placed on your server.
- Through custom code you create a custom EXE bootstrapper which downloads the description file, shows the available options and downloads and installs your packages.

Comment: hi @Cosmin Pirvu is installshield capable of being that bootstrapper? I saw an entry in installshield help which mentioned internet distribution but there's nothing more, could you tell me more on that topic?

Comment: No, it's not. Custom means you need to write it your self. Internet distribution in InstallShield can only download a MSI from an online location. It doesn't do what you need.

Comment: thank you. I will update this session once I got some progress